# How does one specify the input when using a CSV with Kur

Tags: csv, deep-learning

I'm trying to feed a [CSV file](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/iris) to [Kur](http://kur.deepgram.com/index.html), but I don't know how to specify more than one column in the input without the program crashing. Here's a small example:

```
model:
  - input:
      - SepalWidthCm
      - SepalLengthCm
  - dense: 10
  - activation: tanh
  - dense: 3
  - activation: tanh
    name: Species

train:
  data:
    - csv:
        path: Iris.csv
        header: yes
  epochs: 1000
  weights: best.w
  log: tutorial-log

loss:
  - target: Species
    name: mean_squared_error
```

The error:

```
File "/Users/bytter/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/bin/kur", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/bytter/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kur/__main__.py", line 269, in main
    sys.exit(args.func(args) or 0)
  File "/Users/bytter/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kur/__main__.py", line 48, in train
    func = spec.get_training_function()
  File "/Users/bytter/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kur/kurfile.py", line 282, in get_training_function
    model = self.get_model(provider)
  File "/Users/bytter/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kur/kurfile.py", line 148, in get_model
    self.model.build()
  File "/Users/bytter/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kur/model/model.py", line 282, in build
    self.build_graph(input_nodes, output_nodes, network)
  File "/Users/bytter/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kur/model/model.py", line 356, in build_graph
    for layer in node.container.build(self):
  File "/Users/bytter/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kur/containers/container.py", line 281, in build
    self._built = list(self._build(model))
  File "/Users/bytter/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/site-packages/kur/containers/layers/placeholder.py", line 122, in _build
    'Placeholder "{}" requires a shape.'.format(self.name))
kur.containers.parsing_error.ParsingError: Placeholder "..input.0" requires a shape.
```

Using `- input: SepalWidthCm` works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that Kur doesn't know how you want the inputs concatenated. Should your input become 2D tensor of dimensions (2, *N*) (where *N* is the number of data points in your CSV file), like this?

```
[
    [SepalWidthCm_0, SepalWidthCm_1, ...],
    [SepalLengthCm_0, SepalLengthCm_1, ...]
]
```

(*N.B., that example isn't a very deep-learning friendly structure*.) Or should it be combined into a tensor of dimensions (*N*, 2), like this?

```
[
    [SepalWidthCm_0, SepalLengthCm_0],
    [SepalWidthCm_1, SepalLengthCm_1],
    ...
]
```

Or maybe you want to apply the same operations to each column in parallel? Regardless, this problem gets a lot harder / more ambiguous to answer when your input data is multi-dimensional (e.g., instead of scalars like length or width, you have vectors or even matrices).

Instead of trying to guess what you want (and possibly getting it wrong), Kur expects each input to be a single data source, which you can then combine however you see fit.

Here are a couple ways you might want your data combined, and how to do it in Kur.

1. **Row-wise Combination**. This is the second example above, where we want to combine "rows" of CSV data into tuples, so that the input tensor has dimensionality (*batchSize*, 2). Then your Kur model would look like:

   ```
   model:

     # Define the model inputs.
     - input: SepalWidthCm
     - input: SepalLengthCm

     # Concatenate the inputs.
     - merge: concat
       inputs: [SepalWidthCm, SepalLengthCm]

     # Do processing on these "vectorized" inputs.
     - dense: 10
     - activation: tanh
     - dense: 1
     - activation: tanh

     # Output
     - output: Species
   ```
2. **Independent Processing, and then Combining**. This is the setup where you do some operations on each input column independently, and then you merge them together (potentially with some more operations afterwards). In ASCII-art, this might look like:

   ```
   INPUT_1 --> dense, activation --\
                                    +---> dense, activation --> OUTPUT
   INPUT_2 --> dense, activation --/
   ```

   In this case, you would have a Kur model that looks like this:

   ```
   model:

     # First "branch" of processing.
     - input: SepalWidthCm
     - dense: 10
     - activation: tanh
       name: WidthBranch

     # Second "branch" of processing.
     - input: SepalLengthCm
     - dense: 10
     - activation: tanh
       name: LengthBranch

     # Fuse things together.
     - merge:
       inputs: [WidthBranch, LengthBranch]

     # Continue some processing
     - dense: 1
     - activation: tanh

     # Output
     - output: Species
   ```

Keep in mind that the `merge` layer has been around since Kur 0.3, so make sure you using a recent version.

(*Disclaimer: I am the core maintainer of Kur.*)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Adam. May I suggest you has those examples to the documentation? That would be extremely useful :)

Comment: That's a great point! I'll get add to the documentation soon.

Comment: BTW, @adam, I tried to privately contact you through the Deepgram Web Chat. Would you get back to me once you find some time to? Thanks.